# Accessing package private class into other packages in java after refactoring

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on building a android java(jar) library which uses multiple java projects each with same package name.

My structure looks like below,

```
Project A
com.mypackage
  //contains all Package Private Classes

Project B
com.mypackage
  //contains all Package Private Classes + Few Public Classes

Project C
com.mypackage
 //contains all Package Private Classes + Few Public Classes

Project D
// ant script to generate different flavors of Jars( A & B,  A & B & C)
```

**//Consider Project A contains all hidden classes that I don't want to expose**

I am moving this library to Android Gradle build which unfortunately :( doesn't support sub projects with same package names.

I don't want to combine all of them into single package. I want to keep them separate in different packages even if I combine into one Android Studio Project.

If I change the package name in Project A, I need to convert my package private classes in Project A to public so that they can be used in Project B & Project C but that would also make them available to public.

Here are solutions, I thought of,

1. Create interfaces for all package private classes and use interface references in all referenced classes ( huge huge refactoring, I would age faster ). Interfaces would be public but they won't contain implementation.
2. Use android @hide annotation for public classes, not sure if this will work for inter package references

I would really appreciate any suggestion,
Thanks,